# Package for voting systems

Tags: packages

Is there a mathematica package that implements common voting systems (like IRV where voters will rank the candidates)?

Comment: Few methods implemented in Wolfram Demonstrations project [Methods Of Social Choice](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MethodsOfSocialChoice/).

Comment: I have worked on implementing the [Schulze method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schulze_method) in Mathematica. If interested let me know.